# Search from DB by dropdown selection

Tags: laravel

i have no idea how to search by dropdown selection from db column named "emdid" [image]

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="width: 130px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Ангилал <span class="caret"></span> </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Хураамж төлсөн</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Төр хариуцах</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is my text input search

```
$search = $request->get('search');
    $emds = new Emd();
    $emds = $emds->where('registerdugaar', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orderBy("created_at", 'desc')
        ->paginate(15)
        ->withPath('?search=' . $search);
    return view('emd.index', compact('emds'));
```

This is my text input search view , i dont use ajax , and javascript .

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'get']) !!}
<div class="col-lg-2">
<input class="form-control" value="{{ request('search') }}" placeholder="Регистер" name="search" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Хайх</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: You can use ajax request to post search data to your route. If you explain more i can better help you

Comment: what do you want to know ? model ? view ?

Comment: How do you send changed data to your controller? do you use a ajax? Do you use a jquery or pure javascript for check data is change or not?

Comment: @raminashrafimanesh i edited my question please check it out sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use drop downs as  filters for your search query right ? So  first try to use **select lists** instead because unlike drop downs they are **form inputs**

**You can easily style them too look like your dropdowns**

And specify a name for each select

```
<select name="pay">
  <option value="Charge paid">Charge paid</option>
  <option value="government">Paid by government</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller get the input and use it in your query

```
$request->pay
```